# 700ccx28 rims with 25 tread and 28/32 tube does it work?

Tags: fixed-gear

So I have a pure fix, first problem, I replaced the rim strip and the tubes popped far less. I only replaced them a couple times from a nail and too much weight. I needed new tread, the shop owner put on the 25's and the tubes are 28/32 kendas. The tubes popped each time in the same place, near the stem. 3 different tubes. Is this a tube size issue or rim issue?

Comment: Probably your tire pressure is too low, or you are mounting the tires incorrectly.  When you mount the tire, make sure the tube is "sorta" inflated before you insert it, and make sure the stem is square to the rim before inflating the tire.  And use a proper tire pump with pressure gauge when inflating -- you can't go by "feel".

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to find a new shop.

Your typical Velox rim strip should last on the order of decades unless a spoke goes through them or something (and that should be fixed, not just putting a new rim strip), so I'm not sure why it was replaced (or if it was done properly -- right size tape, covering all the spoke holes, aligned with the valve hole which is clean).

The tube size shouldn't be a problem. My suspicion is that you're not running high enough pressure, or aren't installing the tube properly (having the valve free and straight). I'm not sure why the shop owner didn't put a 25c tube in though, considering they're probably the most common size to have on hand.

As for tire wear, using brakes rather than skid stopping reduces tire wear. But, increased tire wear does come with the fixie territory, I suppose. Skidding wears the tire [unequally](http://sheldonbrown.com/fixed.html#skid) depending on the chainring and cog size.